# Adding values from an arraylist of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

Does anyone know how I can sum the values in an arraylist contained inside an arraylist?
For e.g.

```
   ArrayList<Double> arr1=new ArrayList<Double>;
  ArrayList<Double> arr2=new ArrayList<Double>;
```

Let say:                                                                               arr1=[4.5,6.7,8.9,7.3,4.5] 
  arr2=[5.6,7.8,1.3,4.5,3.2]

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> arrayListOfarr1_arr2=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

 arrayListOfarr1_arr2.add(arr1);
 arrayListOfarr1_arr2.add(arr2);
```

How can I it such that  both of the arrayList values can be added together when it points to the same index inside the arrayList the contains them?
For e.g.
sum_of_arr1_arr2=[10.1,14.5,10.2,11.8,7.7]

Comment: If you take a look at the `List` API you [might find something that would help you out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29).

Comment: It looks like you're modelling decimal numbers, so you might find `BigDecimal` to be more accurate than `Double` for this.

Comment: It's a very simple programming problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: @HotLicks Unfortunately I suspect it's too late for that... we've already had the `here's teh codez` answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through your array lists, like so

```
List arr3<Double> = new ArrayList<Double>();

// Set the loop to the size of the smallest array
int loopSize = arr1 < arr2 ? arr1.size() : arr2.size();

for (int x = 0 ; x < loopSize ; x++) {
    arr3.add(arr1.get(x) + arr2.get(x));
}
```

Also, in general we should always try to use `List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();` instead of `ArrayList<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>();`.

Comment: like the part you paid attention to loopSize.